# Change the filter type in queue job in project server 2016 error

Tags: project-server

In Project server 2016, I tried to change the filter type in queue job.

But I got

> Sorry, something went wrong!

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue might occur if many jobs are present in Queue and To overcome this issue you should download and install the [May 2016 Cumulative update](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/06/19/sorry-something-went-wrong-within-manage-queue-jobs-in-project-server-2016/) Which is supposed to solve it based on Microsoft Hotfix Resolved Issue.

You can also check the same issue at [Sorry, something went wrong within Manage Queue Jobs in Project Server 2016](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/06/19/sorry-something-went-wrong-within-manage-queue-jobs-in-project-server-2016/)

Hope it helps you